# Blender running out of memory in renders, but having no problem in previews

Tags: rendering, gpu, memory-management

I am dealing with problem of... Out of memory in cuMemAlloc(&device_pointer, size)
Even though settings are the same in render mode and preview mode I have never encountered this issue in the second one and have it all the time in the first one. 
Note I am rendering on gtx 980ti, memory Peak is usually slightly above 4000M.
If there are no fixes and you have no idea where the problem is. I at least would like to save what I see in preview mode.

Answer (score -1):

preview is not the same as rendering..
you can run out of memory buy a heavier GPU card if your out of memory.
or use a renderfarm or split up the work in layer scenes

Comment: Unfortunately none of these solutions is possible for me, but thanks. I saw that even if image editor bar shows that Memory usage is about 4kM the informations bar shows me about 10kM... which makes no sense. progressive refine seems to make a difference and I can finally render.

Comment: Buying a graphics card just for extra memory? If your render speeds are fine, which should be on a 980ti, you just need to increase your internal RAM, not your video RAM. I suggest you upgrade to at least 16Gb of internal RAM.

Comment: @Hendriks if one has a problem to do GPU rendering adding local RAM wont help. What he might do is reduce texture sizes, but i doubt that, if he has a big scene only a more heavy GPU will work.

And anyone can use a renderfarm in fact its often cheaper then buying a gpu.